# error in ng-scrollbar TypeError: c.mCustomScrollbar is not a function

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I installed jquery angularjs and ng-scrollbars using bower but when I try to use ng-scrollbars I get the following error

```
 TypeError: c.mCustomScrollbar is not a function
    at b (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/ng-scrollbars/dist/scrollbars.min.js:1:288)
    at Object.link
```

this is my base module

var app = angular.module('pro',['ce','restangular','ngScrollbars']);

this is my directive from within which I am calling the ngscrollbars

```
angular.module('pro')
    .directive('pd',function () {
        return{
            bindToController:true,
            scope:{
            dat:'<'
            },
            restrict : 'E',
            templateUrl:'cs.tpl.html',
            controllerAs:'ctrl',
            controller: function() {
                var self = this;
                self.config = {
                    autoHideScrollbar: false,
                    theme: 'light',
                    advanced:{
                        updateOnContentResize: true
                    },
                        setHeight: 200,
                        scrollInertia: 0
                    };

                };
            }
       });
```

this is my template file

```
  <tr ng-scrollbars ng-scrollbars-config="ctrl.config" ng-repeat="spec in specsctrl.dat"><td>{{spec.name}}</td><td>  {{spec.value}}</td></tr>
```

How do I proceed thanks in advance

**Note**:
I am using angularjs 1.5.8 and jquery 3.x

Comment: Could you create a fiddle for it please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was getting the same error too, but it dissapeared after I moved 'jquery.js' and 'mCustomScrollbar.js' scripts before 'angular.js'

```
<script src="/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/scrollbars.min.js"></script>
```